# Pokemon GO: Pokestop Selection Mechanic

Tags: pokemon-go

Having been playing Pokemon GO for the past few days, I would like to know: How is Niantic selecting the pokestops? The reason why I ask is because of how some less popular places get selected for a stop, while popular places that are usually next-door don't have a stop.

**TL;DR:** 
Anyone know what the PokeStop selection process entails? Are there any qualifications? Is there a bias between places? 
Specifically, does anyone know how the game mechanic itself works?

Comment: This may appear like a duplicate, but the post in the link you posted does not explain how a Pokestop is selected. It only talks about where they come from.

Comment: The answer to that question says what list the Pokestops come from. In what way is your question not answered by that?

Comment: I would like to know HOW a Pokestop is selected, what factors lead to it becoming a stop? Whether from another list/ database or not, what made some places a stop and not others? The linked post does not explain any of this.

Comment: The linked question is as far as I can tell, a duplicate - if you want more information than the answer currently provides, please leave a comment there asking for the additional information.